# Redirect to another controller with data

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have an `action_register` function which attempts to register a new user. If successful, I would like the user to be forwarded to the login form (which is shown via `action_login`). However, I'd also like to send a `$message` and `$message_type` to the login view that says something like "Your account has been created, please log in".

What's the best way to do this. By best I mean maintainable, clean and secure.

My ideas up to now:

- POST the data to the url routed to `action_login` and redirect.
- Find a way to send the data right to the controller method and have `action_login` render as always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need to do any snippet of code to set session Message , Fuel php provides a very good interface to handle such feature . Its the core Session Class here is how we need to use as per documentation .

in your case lets say you need to redirect to login_action from register_action and after successful registration process  , then just set the flash message like below

```
Session::set_flash('success', 'Your account has been successfully created !');
```

Later in the view file of the login you can just use the below code to get the flash message that you want . some what like this

```
<?php if (Session::get_flash('success')): ?>
    <div class="alert-box info">
        <?php echo  Session::get_flash('success') ; ?>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also You can delete the session message say 'success' in the above example by just using delete_flash method like below

```
Session::delete_flash('success');
```

To know more about session class you can learn from the link below

[FuelPhp Session Class docuementation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/session/usage.html)

And also to redirect the user you don't need to write any new PHP code, Fuel php gives a nice interface for that too , its the 'Response' class which has methods defined for you to do that

Here is how you need to redirect the user in any of your controller action

```
Response::redirect('yourRouteName');
```

Its always a good practice to exploit the classes defined in the framework , which are actually defined with an intention to make the developers life easy .

Being object oriented in your programming approach especially when using a good quality OOP MVC framework like fuelPhp prevents you from reinventing the wheel always ( [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ) by providing you access to ready made [Getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) .

Hope this helps

Comment: While @Telvin Nguyen's code might work as intended, using the classes that the framework has to offer is the right way to do things. I vote on this one!

Comment: Yeah this is what I was doing when I inquired about setting flash variables instead. Works marvellously.

Answer (score 1):

The message in this case just display one time only (after registration), but I believe in future your project will come with many messages like that.

You should make snippet of code to do that thing and for the resusability
- After you do something as result, you need to store message into a session variable, then redirect to other action
Ex:

```
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Your account has been created, please log in';
```

- On the screen destination, you check if that session variable was set, then you print the message that was stored on session var and clear it.

  ```
          <?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['msg']){
          ?>
          <script>
          //call some javascript function to display popup for example
          var msg = '<?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?>';
          display_popup_message(msg);

          function display_popup_message(msg){
              alert(msg);
          }
          </script>
          <?php
          unset($_SESSION['msg']);
          }
          ?>
  ```

Comment: Ah right session variables, that makes much more sense. Should I maybe set a flash session variable?

Comment: FuelPHP doesn't use PHP native sessions, so by default this will not be passed on to the next request. aravind.udayashankara's anwser is the correct way of doing it.